# Can we covert the guest customer in stripe to real customer?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-payments-js, stripe-customers

I have strange situation ... I want to convert my guest customers in my stripe account to the real customers ... Real customers have the customerID but the guest customer doesn’t have the customer ID ... Is there any way to convert them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guest customers are only available in [Stripe Dashboard](https://support.stripe.com/questions/guest-customer-faq) so there is not a way to manipulate them via the API and there is not an option to convert them to a customer object via the Dashboard.

The recommendation is to create [real customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) moving forward. Although there is not a way to associate previous payments to real customers, you’d be able to track payments that belong to the same customer and create recurring charges. To achieve this, you’d pass the customer object on the [PaymentIntent creation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-customer) or if you’re using Checkout, you’d pass it when [creating the Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer).

Comment: This also answer me that's why I can't use API to list guest customers.